# Почему студия говорит, что не видит тестов там где они есть?

Tags: java, android, юнит-тесты, junit

Вот есть вот такой тестовый метод

```
import com.fittingroom.newtimezone.model.ModelAcceptNotAccept;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import static  android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class PresenterActivityAcceptNotAcceptTest {

@Mock ModelAcceptNotAccept model;

@Before public void setUp() throws Exception {

}

@Test public void setOriginPreviewImage() throws Exception {
    when(model.getImageFilePath()).thenReturn("path");
    String path = model.getImageFilePath();
    assertThat(path, is("path"));
}
```

и при запуске `setOriginPreviewImage()` получаю вот такое

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что сделал не так?

Answer (score 1):

В итоге было все похоже как будто градл просто игнорит зависимости. Все заработало когда я добавил вручную библиотеку в проект

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19